# User Login with Yii2 and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, yii2

Can anyone suggest me how login the user with Yii2 and MongoDB? I have tried below example, they show the same error:

https://github.com/hipstercreative/yii2-user-mongo

https://github.com/sheillendra/yii2-user-mongo/tree/master

I have debug the function one by one and getting the `NULL` result from function `$this->getUser()` which is defined in `LoginForm.php`

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
          return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: check db connection, if its working?

Comment: Yes, i have tested mongodb is connected and fetched the data from table and display it.

Comment: see what it gives Yii::$app->user->identity

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
 *
 * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
 */
public function login() {
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Finds user by [[username]]
 *
 * @return User|null
 */
protected function getUser() {
    if ($this->_user === null) {
        $this->_user = User::find()->where(['email' => $this->emailorphone])->orWhere(['phone' => $this->emailorphone])->one();
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```